# How can I develop for iOS using QT creator on windows 10 from parallels desktop?

Tags: qt, xamarin, deployment, qt-creator, parallels

my workstation is a mac with desktop parallels installed with windows 10.
I currently use Xamarin on Windows and then I get deploy in iOS and Android when I build cross platform apps.

Is it possible to do the same with QT creator? Or I would like to install it on windows 10 on the virtual machine, and start the iOS simulator from QT creator on windows 10. I searched online but found confusing ideas.

Can anyone help me better if you can? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use QtCreator natively on your Mac and compile for Android and/or iOS.
QtCreator starts the matching Simulator for your app, or installs directly on the device. It creates the signed apks and/or ipas for you.
Windows10 is not needed in this workflow.